# AWS Elasticcache Redis Connect using aws ARN

Tags: node.js, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am using AWS Elastic cache redis to few data using node.js. Is there any way to connect aws redis using ARN config instead of HOST.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possbile. The point is: why should you want this?
Using hostname let your application:

1. resolve the host name with the proper ip address, using a RW access and a readonly, if needed
2. change number and type of nodes without any impact on you application

Maybe your problem is that you are using the node hostname, for example:

myredisnode.jltg1a.0001.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com

instead of the balancer hostname:

myredisnode.jltg1a.**ng**.0001.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com

myredisnode**-ro**.jltg1a.**ng**.0001.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com